# Are there group names for gods in Egyptian mythology, similar to the Norse and Greek mythologies primordials, titans, Æsir, Vanir?

Tags: egyptian

Like in the title said is there? If there is mind anyone help me by listing them?

Comment: Why do you think the Egyptians placed their gods in groups?  Can you give examples of thesr groups?

Answer (score 2):

The Egyptian pantheon doesn't distinguish between their gods in the same way (and, in fact, the Norse and Greek groupings aren't really that similar either).

But there are ancient groupings. If you check Wikipedia, the groups of Egyptian deities are [clearly mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Egyptian_deities#Groups_of_deities). However, disappointingly, they neglect to really describe *why* these deities are grouped this way.

Of these, the more famous groupings are the Ennead and Ogdoad, which means "group of nine" and "group of eight" respectively.

The [Ennead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ennead):

> The Ennead or Great Ennead was a group of nine deities in Egyptian mythology worshipped at Heliopolis: the sun god Atum; his children Shu and Tefnut; their children Geb and Nut; and their children Osiris, Isis, Set, and Nephthys.

The [Ogdoad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogdoad_(Egyptian)):

> In Egyptian mythology, the Ogdoad were eight primordial deities worshiped in Hermopolis.

> References to the Ogdoad date to the Old Kingdom of Egypt, and even at the time of composition of the Pyramid Texts toward the end of the Old Kingdom, they appear to have been antiquated and mostly forgotten...

> Nu, Naunet, Ḥeḥu, Ḥeḥut, Kekui, Kekuit, Qerḥ, Qerḥet